# How do I grab this text with preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I have the following HTML code

```
<b>Description: </b>TEXT TO BE GRABBED<br>
```

I need to use preg_match function to grab the "TEXT TO BE GRABBED".

I have tried the following without success:

```
<?php preg_match('#<b>Description: </b>(.*)<br>#', $content, $match); ?>
```

Can someone explain to me the proper method of extracting the text from the HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: RegEx is not the best practice to obtain something from HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse HTML with regex. If you have to do so, then your attempt (in the original question before you edited it) was *almost* right, but you have an extra `/` in `</br>` -- there isn't one in your HTML. You should have:

```
preg_match('#<b>Description: </b>(.*)<br>#', $content, $match);
// $match[1] contains the text "TEXT TO BE GRABBED"
```

[Obligatory link to explain why parsing HTML with regex is bad, very very bad...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919)

Comment: I apologize, this was a typo. I've corrected the post.

Comment: If that was a typo, then what's the problem? Just refer to `$match[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have included in the question works well :

```
<?php
$content = "<b>Description: </b>TEXT TO BE GRABBED<br>";
preg_match('#<b>Description: </b>(.*)<br>#', $content, $match);
print_r($match);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/172133). And when I echo `$match[1]`, I get the value :

> TEXT TO BE GRABBED